# What level is advised to play Mass Effect's Bring Down The Sky DLC?

Tags: mass-effect

Mass Effect's free DLC (on the PC at least) Bring Down the Sky, adds a new system right by the Citadel, Local System and the starter planets of Feros and Noverria.

Is it possible/realistic to play this DLC straight away as a starter character, or should I wait until I've levelled up a bit? If so, what level will it still be a challenge at? I don't want to come back to it at level 50 and find that I can just stroll through it without a challenge.

Is there a rough range of levels where this is possible but still a fun (rather than frustrating) challenge?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible but inadvisable to play Bring Down the Sky from the very beginning. While certainly doable (I've done it myself) you're probably going to end up reloading a dozen times or more over the course of the mission.

The Batarians are no pushoevers, and you've got the always "lovable" varren to deal with, who have a nasty tendency to sneak up behind you and eat you through shields. There is also the issue of one of the torch bunkers spawning rocket drones nigh-continuosly until you take out all the batarian engineers - and everyone knows what sorts of naughty things close-quarter rockets due to Shepard, shielded or not.

I would recommend a level of about 25-30 -- the goal is that you have enough abilities by that point to survive a little longer than you might otherwise. But, level alone isn't the best indicator of difficulty in this game; if you've already beaten the game once, you should have the VII spectre master weapons available as soon as you can afford them, and a good gun and good knowledge of cover will serve you better than the extra 100 health successive levels will give you.

Comment: Thanks, on my first play-through (hence the question) so don't have the Spectre Master weapons available will give it a go around those levels.

Answer (score 2):

I beat it at level 12, but I had to reload a bunch of times.  I didn't even know I was doing the expansion until I got the achievement.

Answer (score 0):

I made it at level 10 (leveled up to 11 at almost the end of it, and the only time I died was because I got too close to a blasting cap. It wasn't that hard, actually... But, because my level was so low, and I'd been focusing on leveling up my combat power, my decryption skill was too low to open a few containers.